# How to connect on Grafana and Prometheus containers running inside WSL2

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm running Prometheus and Grafana as containers inside WSL2 and I'm not able to connect on them from Windows. I'm receiving the error `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9090` (connection refused).

When I acces them from inside the WSL2 everything works.

### docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
  prometheus:

    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yaml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
    network_mode: "host"

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/data
    network_mode: "host"

volumes:
  prometheus_data:
  grafana_data:
```

### ./prometheus/prometheus.yaml

```yaml
global:
alerting:
rule_files:
scrape_configs:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's a problem when the server running inside WSL2 is on `:::` address, like the default address from Grafana - `http.server address=[::]:3000`.

If the host name is changed to 127.0.0.1, everything works.

### Changing server IP address from Grafana and Prometheus to 127.0.0.1

On Prometheus, it is necessary to add this command `--web.listen-address=127.0.0.1:9090`.

On Grafana, it is necessary to add this environment variable `GF_SERVER_HTTP_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"`

### docker-compose.yaml with host names set to 127.0.0.1

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
  prometheus:

    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yaml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
      - '--web.listen-address=127.0.0.1:9090'
    network_mode: "host"

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/data
    environment:
      GF_SERVER_HTTP_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"
    network_mode: "host"

volumes:
  prometheus_data:
  grafana_data:
```